# Allowing an Ionic app access a s3 bucket with Bucket Policy

Tags: ionic-framework, amazon-s3

I have a web application who gets videos from an s3 bucket. That bucket has a policy to only allow the access from certain domains. I now need an ionic app to access the same bucket, is there any way I can add this option to the policy?

Here is the policy as I have it now

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com.",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.mp4",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.example.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried adding `file://*` to the urls array but won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use User-Agent to identify request coming from your app.

Here is code for the Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.mp4",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": "*Any name"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Also you have to add in your config.xml

```
<preference name="AppendUserAgent" value="Any name" />
```